# How can I more efficiently paint grass onto a large terrain object in Unity?

Tags: unity, terrain

I'm trying to paint a grass onto a large terrain and I want it to cover the entire terrain. Since the brush size can't go past 100 it would seem that I'm stuck painting the entire thing with a small brush relative to the terrain size.

How can I more efficiently paint grass onto a large terrain object?

Comment: No way, just paint sadly

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely "paint" a texture programmatically onto the Alphamaps of the terrain.  Take a look at the TerrainData component and the Alphamaps methods / properties

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.SetAlphamaps.html

## Things to know going in:

- the terrain stores the textures `AlphamapTextures` you can use to paint on it.
  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData-alphamapTextures.html
- `Alphamaps` in this case are just a multi-dimmensional array containing X and Y position as well as the texture data used at that position

With this info one could presumably blanket the whole terrain with one texture at run time...  Or if clever enough / build a Custom Editor script with a button to call a method that does this before compile time.  That way you could save that terrain as a prefab / save the scene and not have to rely on spending runtime resources to do something trivial... or really whatever your little pixelated hearts desire